# Intellisense not working when instancing a subclass as a collection

Tags: vba, intellisense

I am having problem with intellisense when instancing a subclass inside of a Collection within a main class. The program runs as expected but it's still annoying not to get the intellisense. *Is there a way of sparking VBA to run intellisense and know what object it is really working on?*

I have tried with an array instead but then I need to implement a .Count method somehow.

My simplified example have three modules:

**`Module1.bas`**

```
Sub run()
    Dim Samsung As New TV
    Samsung.Name = "TV livingroom"

    Samsung.AddOwner "John", "Smith"
    Samsung.AddOwner "Santa", "Claus"
    Samsung.PreviousOwners(1).LastName = "Johnson"
    Samsung.PreviousOwners(1).                      ' Intellisense not working here

    Debug.Print "The name of the TV is: " & Samsung.Name
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Samsung.PreviousOwners.Count
        Debug.Print "Owner " & CStr(i) & " is named " & Samsung.PreviousOwners(i).FullName
    Next i
End Sub
```

**`TV.cls`**

```
Option Explicit
'
Public Name As String
Public PreviousOwners As Collection

Public Sub AddOwner(fName As String, lName As String)
    Dim newOwner As New OwnerInfo
    newOwner.FirstName = fName
    newOwner.LastName = lName
    If PreviousOwners Is Nothing Then Set PreviousOwners = New Collection
    PreviousOwners.Add newOwner
End Sub
```

**`OwnerInfo.cls`**
    Option Explicit

```
Public pFirstName As String
Public pLastName As String

Public Property Get FirstName() As String
    FirstName = pFirstName
End Property
Public Property Let FirstName(arg As String)
    pFirstName = arg
End Property
Public Property Get LastName() As String
    LastName = pLastName
End Property
Public Property Let LastName(arg As String)
    pLastName = arg
End Property

Public Function FullName() As String
    FullName = FirstName & " " & LastName
End Function
```

**`Debug output`**

```
The name of the TV is: TV livingroom
Owner 1 is named John Johnson
Owner 2 is named Santa Claus
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of properties in a class (in this case, the `TV` class). The simple version is:

```
Property Get ParticularPreviousOwner(index as long) as OwnerInfo
    Set ParticularPreviousOwner = PreviousOwners(index)
End Property

Property Get AllPreviousOwners() as Collection
    Set AllPreviousOwners = PreviousOwners
End Property
```

The first property directly answers your question by strongly typing the response, which VBA can now use with Intellisense. Otherwise, you are just returning a `Variant` which Intellisense does not have any idea on how to interpret.

With the pair of properties above you can now hide (make `Private`) your class members - hide the workings of the class and control the interfaces. You almost got there with your `OwnerInfo` class - make `pFirstName` and `pLastName` `Private`:

```
Private pFirstName As String
Private pLastName As String
```

Also (horses for courses), you could make `FullName` a `Property` as well, rather than a `Function` in this case.

**Important**: I have provided a bare bones example. Error checking is required to make sure that only sensible results are returned regardless of what the code passes for `index`. Once you get used to doing this, you can end up with some powerful and very useful classes that you can re-use many times.

Comment: Yes, I tried with properties and keeping the collection private but having them (`PreviousOwners`) as public collections was the only thing that worked with both getting info about the collection (ex `Samsung.PreviousOwners.Count`) and information about a specific owner (ex `Samsung.PreviousOwners(2).FirstName`).

I would also like to avoid having multiple like sounding properties like ParticularPreviousOwner and AllPreviousOwners because there can be many "fields" like Owner.

Comment: @danneedebro: and now I have given you another way that works. Exactly as you would like. Except safer because you can do further checks and controls.

Answer (score 0):

What you need can be accomplished by creating custom collection plus *default property*.

Here's the basic skeleton. You can adjust this custom collection to your needs.

**`TV.cls`**

```
Public Name As String
Public Make As String
```

**`TVCollection.cls`**

```
Private m_Coll As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_Coll = New Collection
End Sub

Property Get Item(index) As TV
    Set Item = m_Coll(index)
End Property

Public Function Add(varTV As TV)
    m_Coll.Add Item:=varTV
End Function

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = m_Coll.Count
End Property
```

Then you can use this collection (with working IntelliSense):

```
Sub FFF()
    Dim col As New TVCollection
    Dim varTV As TV
    Set varTV = New TV
    varTV.Name = "Some TV"
    col.Add varTV
    MsgBox col.Item(1).Name '// "Some TV"
    col.Item(1).Name = "Another TV"
    MsgBox col.Item(1).Name '// "Another TV"
End Sub
```

However, you want to write `col(1)` rather `col.Item(1)`. In order to do it, you need to manually edit `.cls` file in order to make `Item` property default. Here's what you need to do:

1) Right-click on `TVCollection` module and press `Remove TVCollection`. In appeared dialog box select `Yes`. Choose location for saving.

2) Open save `TVCollection.cls` class with text editor and go to `Property Get Item(index) As TV` line.

3) Now right beneath it insert the following code:

```
Property Get Item(index) As TV
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Set Item = m_Coll(index)
End Property
```

4) Save changes and import this class back to VBE: **File -> Import File...**

Now you can write this way and IntelliSense will work fine:

```
MsgBox col(1).Name
```

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UClAsqKTD7UyRz-6ZC) you can download workbook with code.

Comment: I am not sure this is what I am looking for. For me that would mean that i have methods like `Samsung.Count` that is suppose to count previous owners. I might have many collections like owners in my TV-class and it is desireable to have the count method beneth the PreviousOwners to reduce the number of properties and methods at each level.

Comment: I added an own answer to my question that perhaps clarifies what I want to be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question as I found a good way to solve the problem.

The run sub below describes what functionality I am interested in having (and have succeded with+intellisense). I find the three-like structure `Samsung.PreviousOwners.Count` more aesthetically pleasing than something like `Samsung.CountPreviousOwners`.

Also, the *polymorphism*-like behaviour of being able to refer to both `Samsung.PreviousOwners` for information about the set and `Samsung.PreviousOwners(2)` for a specific owner.

**`Module.bas`**

```
Sub run()
    Dim Samsung As New TV
    Samsung.Name = "TV livingroom"

    ' Add with TV-method AddOwner (NOT aesthetically pleasing!)
    Samsung.AddOwner "John", "Smith"
    Samsung.AddOwner "Santa", "Claus"

    ' Add with Constructor-like method in OwnerInfo class (more aesthetically pleasing!)
    Samsung.PreviousOwners.AddOwner "Bill", "Clinton"

    ' Add with Collection-like Add method
    Dim NewOwner As New OwnerInfo
    NewOwner.FirstName = "George"
    NewOwner.LastName = "Bush"
    Samsung.PreviousOwners.Add NewOwner

    ' Replace owner 2 with new owner
    Set NewOwner = New OwnerInfo
    NewOwner.FirstName = "Karl"
    NewOwner.LastName = "Jung"
    Samsung.PreviousOwners(2) = NewOwner

    ' Number of owners
    Debug.Print "Number of previous owners: " & CStr(Samsung.PreviousOwners.Count)

    Debug.Print "The name of the TV is: " & Samsung.Name
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Samsung.PreviousOwners.Count
        Debug.Print "Owner " & CStr(i) & " is named " & Samsung.PreviousOwners(i).FullName
    Next i
End Sub
```

This code outputs the following and intellisense works

**`Output`**

```
Number of previous owners: 4
The name of the TV is: TV livingroom
Owner 1 is named John Smith
Owner 2 is named Karl Jung
Owner 3 is named Bill Clinton
Owner 4 is named George Bush
```

Basically, what I have changed is

**In `TV.cls`**:

- Changed public variable PreviousOwners to private pPreviousOwners
- New PreviousOwners **Get property** with optional argument 'index'. If no argument is given (-1) then set PreviousOwners as a new OwnersInfo-class and pass the 'pPreviousOwners' variable as a argument to a `GlobalInit` -method
- New PreviousOwners **Set and Let property**

**In `OwnersInfo.cls`**:

- New private member variable 'pContainer' as a Collection
- New "constructor" GlobalInit that takes the container collection as argument
- New public method "Add" to mirror the Collection-Add method
- New public method "Count" to mirror the Collection-Count method

Here is the code:

**`TV.cls`**

```
Option Explicit
'
Public Name As String
Private pPreviousOwners As Collection

' Properties
Public Property Get PreviousOwners(Optional index As Integer = -1) As OwnerInfo
    ' If no index is given, pass the pPreviousOwners as argument to a OwnersInfo.GlobalInit-method
    If index = -1 Then
        Dim GlobalOwnerInfo As New OwnerInfo
        GlobalOwnerInfo.GlobalInit pPreviousOwners
        Set PreviousOwners = GlobalOwnerInfo
    Else
        Set PreviousOwners = pPreviousOwners(index)
    End If
End Property

Public Property Let PreviousOwners(index As Integer, arg As OwnerInfo)
    ' Need to copy pPreviousOwners
    Dim NewColl As New Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To pPreviousOwners.Count
        If i = index Then NewColl.Add arg Else NewColl.Add pPreviousOwners(i)
    Next i
    Set pPreviousOwners = NewColl
End Property

Public Property Set PreviousOwners(index As Integer, arg As OwnerInfo)
    PreviousOwners(index) = arg  ' Reuse the Let property
End Property

' Class event methods
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pPreviousOwners = New Collection
End Sub


' Methods
Public Sub AddOwner(fName As String, lName As String)
    Dim NewOwner As New OwnerInfo
    NewOwner.FirstName = fName
    NewOwner.LastName = lName
    If pPreviousOwners Is Nothing Then Set pPreviousOwners = New Collection
    pPreviousOwners.Add NewOwner
End Sub
```

**`OwnersInfo.cls`**

```
Option Explicit

Public FirstName As String
Public LastName As String

Private pContainer As Collection  ' A reference to the container collection (to get global count)

' Class event methods
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pContainer = New Collection
End Sub

' Methods
Public Sub GlobalInit(ByRef colContainer As Collection)
    Set pContainer = colContainer
End Sub

Public Function Count() As Integer
    Count = pContainer.Count
End Function

Public Sub Add(NewObject As Object)
    pContainer.Add NewObject
End Sub

Public Sub AddOwner(ByVal fName As String, ByVal lName As String)
    Dim NewOwner As New OwnerInfo
    NewOwner.FirstName = fName
    NewOwner.LastName = lName
    pContainer.Add NewOwner
End Sub

Public Function FullName() As String
    FullName = FirstName & " " & LastName
End Function
```